# TYPE APPLICATION OVERLAY in android 11 permission denied

Tags: java, android, android-overlay

I tried to create a overlay app for android 11 and I see that I can't use the

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY" />
```

in android 11 only if this is a system app
so I make it for a system app and I still not able to preform a system overlay
I get this error

```
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@10f390 -- permission denied for window type 2006
```

Comment: How do you make it a system app? Are you working on your own Android source? There's no way to put your app as system unless you either root your device or building your own Android

Comment: I have root access and its possible to build it with a system signature as well

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

Your TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY requires

> Requires Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

Data can be found https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Did you request that specific permission and did you grant it? (Even though if you are system app it's probably granted